# parsing json with php curl

Tags: php, json, curl

I have the following json :

```
{"returnCode":0,"returnMessage":"SUCCESS","data":{"OrganizationName":"ABC inc."}}
```

I wrote the following code to parse the organization name. But it is not working.

```
$response = json_decode($server_output, true);
 foreach($response['data'] as $item)
 {
   echo $item['OrganizationName'];

}
```

Comment: THe issue is data isn't an array. You need to access it like an object $response->data->OrganizationName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `foreach` use below code to get OrganizationName

```
 $response = json_decode($server_output, true);
 $response['data']['OrganizationName'];
```

Answer (score 2):

i think json_decode() function work for you.

```
$array= curl_exec ($ch);
$server_output =json_decode($array);
$server_output->data->OrganizationName // output ABC inc.
```

Comment: please see my edit. I have made the change but it is returning only the first letter A of organization.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access it as an array, typecast it.

```
$response = (array) json_decode($server_output);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to foreach you can directly access the Organization name.

Check below code

```
$server_output='{"returnCode":0,"returnMessage":"SUCCESS","data":{"OrganizationName":"ABC inc."}}';

$response = json_decode($server_output);

echo $response->data->OrganizationName; // ABC inc.
```